# Comparing columns with pandas_schema

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, validation, schema

I am using python 3.8 and Pandas_schema to run integrity checks on data. I have a requirement that `workflow_next_step` should never be the same as `workflow_entry_step`. I'm trying to generate a CustomSeriesValidation that compares both columns because I do not see a stock function that does this.

Is there a way to compare two cell values in the same row using Pandas_Schema? In this example, Pandas_Schema would return an error for Mary because she was moved from `In Progress` to `In Progress`.

```
df = config.pd.DataFrame({
'prospect': ['Bob', 'Jill', 'Steve', 'Mary'], 
'value': [10000, 15000, 500, 50000],
'workflow_entry_step': ['New', 'In Progress', 'Closed', 'In Progress'], 
'workflow_next_step': ['In Progress', 'Closed' ,None, 'In Progress']})

schema = Schema([
Column('prospect', [LeadingWhitespaceValidation(), TrailingWhitespaceValidation()]),
Column('value', [CanConvertValidation(int),'Doesn\'t convert to integer.']),
Column('workflow_entry_step', [InListValidation([None,'New','In Progress','Closed'])]),
Column('workflow_next_step', [CustomSeriesValidation(lambda x: x != Column('workflow_entry_step'), InListValidation([None,'New','In Progress','Closed'])]), 'Steps cannot be the same.')])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
'prospect': ['Bob', 'Jill', 'Steve', 'Mary'], 
'value': [10000, 15000, 500, 50000],
'workflow_entry_step': ['New', 'In Progress', 'Closed', 'In Progress'], 
'workflow_next_step': ['In Progress', 'Closed' ,None, 'In Progress']})

schema = Schema([
Column('prospect', [LeadingWhitespaceValidation(), TrailingWhitespaceValidation()]),
Column('value', [CanConvertValidation(float)]),
Column('workflow_entry_step', [InListValidation([None,'New','In 
Progress','Closed'])]),
Column('workflow_next_step', [CustomSeriesValidation(lambda x: x != 
df['workflow_entry_step'], 'Steps cannot be the same.'), 
InListValidation([None,'New','In Progress','Closed'])])
])
errors = schema.validate(df)
for error in errors:
    print(error)
```

Output:

```
{row: 3, column: "workflow_next_step"}: "In Progress" Steps cannot be the same.
```

Comment: That solution does not work for me. 

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().